# Reactive Extentions in Orleans grain code

Tags: c#, system.reactive, orleans

there has been a major update in https://github.com/dotnet/reactive project:

> v4.0 changes
>
> Ix Async 4.0 has a breaking change from prior versions due to being
>   the first LINQ implementation to **support the new C# 8 async streams
>   feature.** This means for .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET Core 3 targets, we
>   use the in-box interfaces for IAsyncEnumerable and friends. On
>   other platforms, we provide the implementation, so you can use await
>   foreach and create async iterators as you would expect. The types will
>   unify to the system ones where the platform provides it.
>
> There are many breaking changes here; a full set of change notes is on
>   the way.

Can this library be used in Orleans code to process streams in grains?  I am aware that RX uses its own scheduler to run observers and subscriptions (e.g. `ObserveOn()` and `SubscribeOn()`), and I am curious if that would conflict with Orlean's own scheduler, or if there is a way to make RX to respect, or make use of Orlean's task runner by passing it to RX in the above methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the latest update on [GitHub issue #315](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/315), [Rx.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) is not supported in Orleans. In theory it should work, and the suggestion was to look at using something like:

```
var rxScheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler(new TaskFactory(RuntimeContext.Current));
```

I also didn't find anything helpful in the [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/dotnet/orleans) history.